# How to launch chrome on fullscreen using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, fullscreen

I have been trying to use node js libaray called opn. I can use this libaray perfectly and able to launch the chrome using nodejs but I can't launch the app in kiose/fullscreen mode. I have tried different chrome command but nothing worked.

```
opn('http://localhost:2222', {app: ['chrome', '--kiosk']});
```

above code takes '--incognito' and launched incognito mode but --kiosk didn't launch kiosk mode. Can anyone suggest me how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the flag `--start-fullscreen`? The [Documentation](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#start-fullscreen) suggests this would do the trick.

Comment: thank you for the repl. :) yes I did try but no luck.